# Stream in Bigquery Storage API Read Session, How to get Stream Meta Data like Number of Page

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using the STORAGE API to turn a large table into a PYTHON DATAFRAME. Here, when using multiple STREAMs, it seems that a table of a certain size is allocated to each stream. At this time, what should we do when we want to know in advance how much data to read from each stream?

```
 `requested_session = types.ReadSession(
        table=table,
        data_format=types.DataFormat.ARROW,
        read_options=read_options,
    )
 read_session = bqstorageclient.create_read_session(
       parent=parent,
       read_session=requested_session,
       max_stream_count=4
   )

 stream = read_session.streams[3]`
```

I want the stream size to be 9998 rows.